# MySQL treats "y" as "i"

Tags: mysql

My simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT `word`  FROM  `nouns`  WHERE  `word` LIKE  'vandenys'
```

Returns:

> vandenis

But "vandenYs" and "vandenIs" is not the same.

Where is the problem and how to prevent from that?

Collation: utf8_lithuanian_ci

Framework: Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the utf8_lithuanian_ci collation, those two letters are equal.

http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_lithuanian_ci.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html

If that's not what you want, use a different collation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41106

Comment: Per status and comments on that page, it is not a bug, those letters are equal under that collation as intended.

Comment: Its more likely a real Lithuanian sorting rule - like ll' = y in terms of dictionary order in spanish

Comment: @tobyodavies: but "equality in order" does not imply "equal". In German (in some collations, not all), "ä" and "a" are sorted equivalently. And still "Bär" and "Bar" are two entirely different words.

Comment: In German, at least as i was taught it, "ss" and a scharfes S were equal - the same word could be spelled with or without one. So 'heisse' and 'heiße' are in fact the same word, so yes there is a difference between equal and sorting the same, this does not preclude the former.

Comment: @tobyodavies: well, kind-of. "ß" *can* be written as "ss" if "ß" is not available (for example when typing on an english keyboard or when using all-capitals). But if there's nothing from stoping you to type a "ß", then using "ss" is not strictly correct.

Comment: As i was taught ß is actually old-fashioned and the official line on the subject was that it should be spelled 'ss' but then i'm no native speaker

Comment: @tobyodavies: this is where it gets really nasty: the usage of "ß" in the official rules has been reduced recently, but it has *not* been removed entirely. They changed just enough to force everyone to relearn, but didn't change enough to make it really easy.

Comment: Fun! I'm glad all the letters in English are _really_ different :D